# Maven versions plugin is not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I need to find a Maven plugin which will update the project versions(There should not be any SCM dependencies)

For example :

> change from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to 1.0.0
>
> change from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1
>
> change from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0
>
> change from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT

So, I was searching for a plugin and I found [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)
.
When I am manually setting the version using versions:set it is working perfectly fine. But, when I need to update it in an incremental fashion I was unable to do it.
I used **versions:use-next-releases** and **versions:use-next-snapshots** along with the parameter : **-DallowSnapshots=true**.
I am not sure why exactly it is not working.

Note:

1. My project is a simple Java project. I created the java project first and then converted it to Maven project.
2. I used the dependency as below:

   org.codehaus.mojo
               versions-maven-plugin
               2.1
               
                   v@{project.version}
3. I can not use **maven release plugin** as my code does not have any SCM.

What is the wrong I am doing here?
Please help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: You have written you use `org.codehaus.mojo versions-maven-plugin` as dependency ? Did i understand correctly ? Yes than it does not make sense to have a plugin as dependency. Please show your pom file...

Answer (score 1):

Both of these goals (as stated by its documentation) check if the artifact has been released/deployed. Since you are not using any SCM, the plugin probably gets confused.

You could try doing an `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=XXX`. It's not as automatic as you would like, but it'll do the trick. We use use it every now and then; it just does a "blind" update  (i.e it doesn't check the artifact's SCM, release or deploy status) of the POM's version and `parent.version` if there is one.